# Perl OOP Blessing

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and I've been making my way through this tutorial http://qntm.org/files/perl/perl.html

Anyways, I'm working on creating a package that will take in a matrix and will perform various basic operations (i.e. gaussian elimination, rref, back sub, deterimants, etc). I have my constructor taking in a list of references, but I'm having some trouble blessing them so I can access them later. My code thus far:

main.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Matrix;

my @list = ([1,1,1],[2,2,2]);
my $matrix = Matrix->new(@list);

$matrix->test();
```

Matrix.pm:

```
package Matrix;
    sub new(){
        my $class = shift;
        my $self = [];

        my @params = @_;
        $self = \@params;

        print scalar @{$self->[1]}; #just testing some output...(outputs 3 as expected)

        bless $self,$class;

        return $self;
    }

    sub test(){
        print @{$self->[1]}; #does not output anything
    }

1;
```

I'm assuming the problem is that the references that $self is referring to is not being blessed, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to actually define `$self` in `test`; it's not available for you automatically.  This is why you should always put `use warnings; use strict;` in every Perl source file: so that the compiler will tell you about errors like these.  (Also, there's no point in writing `sub new()` instead of `sub new`, and likewise for `test`; the function prototype is not only wrong but will be flat-out ignored when `new` is used as a method, i.e., how `new` is supposed to be used.)

Comment: Yes.  Those should be `sub new` and `sub test`, no parentheses.  And the first line of `test` should be `my $self = shift;`.  You would have gotten some help if you'd put `use strict` and `use warnings` in `Matrix.pm` as well as `main.pl` - as lexical declarations, those don't extend to included modules.

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working now! Can you explain why I need the shift? When called without an argument, I thought that shift removes and returns the first value in @_ (which should be empty since I'm not passing any arguments to test).

Comment: @William: You *are* passing arguments to `test`.  The first argument to any method call is always the object or class name on which the method was invoked.